# SSRS Format Numeric not summarizing in excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, excel-2013

I need to set a format for a column when the column "KPI" has a value with '%' I need that the value has the format for a percentage otherwise the currency format, so I have something like this:

```
=IIF(InStr(Fields!KPI.Value,"%")>0,Format(Fields!DIA.Value, "P"),Format(Fields!DIA.Value, "C"))
```

That expression works properly, but when I try to export that report to excel, that column is not summarizing when I select several columns as you will see in this picture:

[image]

As you can see excel is recounting but not summarizing, I have tried formatting each field from SQL Server and with this formula:

```
=IIF(InStr(Fields!KPI.Value,"%")>0,Format(Fields!DIA.Value, "###.#%"),Format(Fields!DIA.Value, "###,###,###,###.##"))
```

But the same happend when I export that report to excel, is there another way to handle this?

Comment: Excel is not interpreting correctly the cells values, you have to change the decimal and thousand separator in your Excel installation according to your report, or vice versa. Check [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-character-used-to-separate-thousands-or-decimals-c093b545-71cb-4903-b205-aebb9837bd1e)

Comment: Uhmm this report is for many people that means that I would have to change the excel configuration for all that person, That's a risk because other files can stop working properly for them.

Comment: If it is important that the numbers be interpreted as numbers in Excel correctly, you could use the RenderFormat global variable to detect when the report is being rendered for Excel and not include the problematic formatting characters: `=IIF(InStr(Fields!KPI.Value,"%")>0,Format(Fields!DIA.Value, "###.#%"),IIF(OR(Globals!RenderFormat.Name="EXCELOPENXML",Globals!RenderFormat.Name="EXCEL"),Fields!DIA.Value,Format(Fields!DIA.Value, "###,###,###,###.##")))`

Answer (score 0):

In order to make sure that Excel interprets a value as numeric, you can use the RenderFormat global variable to detect when the report is being rendered for Excel and not include the problematic formatting characters:

```
=IIF(InStr(Fields!KPI.Value,"%")>0,Format(Fields!DIA.Value, "###.#%"),IIF(OR(Globals!RenderFormat.Name="EXCELOPENXML",Gl‌​obals!RenderFormat.N‌​ame="EXCEL"),Fields!‌​DIA.Value,Format(Fie‌​lds!DIA.Value, "###,###,###,###.##")))
```

If its critical that you display a thousands separator in your generated output you can use the Language global variable to detect the user's region and use the appropriate character.  That check would take the general form `Globals.Lanuage="en-US"`, depending on what particular regions are involved.

Here's an example of using the RenderFormat.Name variable to check the renderer in VS2013:

[image: RenderFormat Layout]

When doing a preview of the report, the format will show that the render type is RPL:

[image: RenderFormat Preview]

Comment: I don't know why I can't use Globals!RenderFormat.Name, visual studio 2013 shows an error, it looks like that variable doesn't exists, I get this error in preview mode: The Value expression for the textrun 'DIA1.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' contains an error: [BC30037] Character is not valid.

Comment: What SQL server version are you running?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4100.1 (X64) 
 Apr 20 2015 17:29:27 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Are you sure that the TargetServerVersion of the project is for R2 and not just 2008?  I specifically checked VS2013 and included an example above.  However, I know that particular global was only added in R2, hence my question.